# Jquery Remove Clear Top CSS attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a hover over button, once hovered it will scroll up to unreal more content over my slideshow, but when I hover over the button it pulls up but wont come back down.

[Click here to see live, hover over Contact Our Team Button on slider](http://3rdsectorprojects.com/live/)

```
jQuery(".buttontwo").hover(
                    function(e){
                        jQuery('.buttontwo').animate({top:'0px', bottom:'auto'}, 200)
                        },
                    function(e){
                        jQuery('.buttontwo').animate({bottom:'75px', top:'auto'}, 200) 
                        }  
       );
```

Any ideas guys?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a fixed value to the `top` property in the second `function()`.

However you should be aware that as soon as you hover the button and the animation starts the second function will be triggered since you're not hovering the button anymore.

You might have to find a different way to animate that, perhaps adding a`onMouseEnter` / `onMouseLeave` event to the button's container.

Comment: I cannot use a fixed value due to it being a responsive slider, it needs either top to be 0 and bottom to be 75px; Thanks for reply tho

Comment: You can work out where to move it based on the next element's position.